# How to set minimum height for Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

I am using multiple Web Views and adding it in a layout, my structure is like this

Linear Layout
 
|
|----------------|
    Webview 
|----------------|
     Webview 
|----------------|
     Webview 
|----------------|

I want to set minimum height for weview, so that all cells will looks similar.

I have tried with

```
setMinimumHeight(int minHeight)
```

But its not working. I have also checked with

```
cellLayout.addView(mWebview, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80));
```

It works perfectly fine but it restricts with values 80.

If HTML content is more then size then it will show a scroll.

So I am looking for minimum height, so if content is more then minmum height, it will automatically warp the content.

How to set minimum height for WebView ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it out with using below code.
you can put the following in the `onPageFinished` event for the WebView and it does the job for me of fixing the dialog height after the html content has been loaded.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    ....
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (webView.getHeight() < currentHeight) {
          currentHeight = webView.getHeight();
        }
        final LayoutParams params = webView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = currentHeight;
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: buddy it will not work because he is asking for setting the minimum height and this will just wrap the content without scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int parentHeight = 0;
    if (getParent() != null && getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
        parentHeight = ((ViewGroup) getParent()).getHeight();
    }
    if (height < parentHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), parentHeight);
    }
}
```

I met the same problem with you and I solved it like this. Hope it can help you. You just need override onMeasure function in WebView and replace the parentHeight to the minimum height you need.